# How to delete comments from database?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am trying to delete comments from my admin panel.I have a function for delete comments but I dont know why this isn't working.

**Here is my controller:**

```
$article = \DB::table("events")
    ->where("id", $id)
    ->select("id", "subject", "information", "public", "category_id", "event_type_id", "country", "address", "city", "starts", "ends", "organizer", "website", "email", "telephone")
    ->first();

    $data['article'] = $article;

$event_comm = EventComment::where('event_id', $id)->get();


return view("admin.editEvent", $data)
            ->with(compact('event_comm'));
```

**My delete comments function:**

```
public function deleteComment($type, $id)
    {
        if($type == "Event")
        {
            $comment = \App\EventComment::find($id);
        }
    if($type == "Opinion")
        {
            $comment = \App\OpinionComment::find($id);
        }
         $comment->delete();

        return redirect('admin/comments'); 
    }
```

**Route for deletecomment**

```
Route::get('admin/article/deleteComment/{type?}/{id?}', 'ArticleController@deleteComment');
```

**My button**

```
 <button href="{{ url('admin/article/deleteComment/'.$article['type'].'/'.$article['id']) }}" role="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this comment?');">Delete <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

Comment: you pass comment id..? or event id ?

Comment: `{type?}/{id?}` - Why the question marks? Looking at the controller, both arguments should be required.

Comment: so should I delete question marks?

Comment: You also never check if you actually got a comment before you try to delete it. If someone passes in an invalid type or id, you wouldn't get a comment back. Do some debugging to see if all the values are what you expect and that `$comment` is defined.

Comment: Question marks are for _optional_ arguments. So if you visit `admin/article/deleteComment/`, you will get an error since the controller expects two arguments but would get none. [Here's the manual about route parameters](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: yes, you are right. I've got this error : `
ErrorException in ArticleController.php line 510:
Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController::deleteComment()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

Please change your route like

```
Route::get('admin/article/deleteComment/{type}/{id}', 'ArticleController@deleteComment')->name('commentdelete');
```

Your button like:

```
 <button href="{{ route('commentdelete',[$article['type'],$article['id']]) }}" role="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this comment?');">Delete <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir.Do you know why my modal isn't opened when I press edit button?Without `href="{{ route('commentdelete',[$article['type'],$article['id']]) }}"` it's working, but I need that, how to use it correctly?I'm using laravel 5.2

Comment: Yes it's correct method for laravel and you can use url and route name in anchor tag

Comment: If my answer work for you then please accept and upvote to my answer

Comment: Wait a moment pls, do you know why my modal isn't open now?Here is code for my edit modal : `<a article_type="{{ $article['type'] }}" pop_up_id="{{ $article['type'] }}_{{ $article['id'] }}" role="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning modify">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
         </a>

         <div class="modal" id="myModal_{{ $article['type'] }}_{{ $article['id'] }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
`

Comment: Because when your make any route in modal href then when you click on button that time they redirect on route so please when you use href for popup modal then just write href="#"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196316/discussion-between-andrei-nagy-and-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route'=>['comments.destroy', $comment->id], 'style'=> 'display:inline', 'onsubmit' => 'return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")']) !!}
{!! Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',['type'=>'submit', 'class'=> 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Create a route like this

```
Route::delete('comments/{id}',['uses'=>'CommentsController@destroy', 'as' => 'comments.destroy']);
```

Comment: A good answer includes an _explanation_ of why the OP should "try this". What have you changed and why? Also, looking at the code, the OP needs the `type`-value as well to know what type of comment to remove.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But not working for moment, when I press edit button, my modal doesn't open to see my fields to edit. Here is how should like : https://imgur.com/a/RxQKIT4